# В заданной строке удалить первый символ

Tags: c++

```
char str[80] = "faE1*fe A3iBVf Oq eof 43GFW2jiqe[ qe";
char token[80];

char *p = str;
char *t = token;

cout << str << endl;

while (*p){
    if (*p != str[0]){
        *t = *p;
        ++t;
    }
    ++p;
}
*t = 0;

cout << token << endl;
```

У меня удаляет все символы равные 1-ому символу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить строку, начиная со второго символа? Более оптимальное решение:

```
int sz = strlen(str);
memmove(str, str + 1, sz - 1);
str[sz - 1] = 0;
```

Или поправьте в вашем решении с `if (*p != str[0]){` на `if(p != str){`

Ну, а вообще, правильное решение поставленной задачи: `char *token = str + 1;`

Comment: s/memcpy/memmove/, http://c-faq.com/ansi/memmove.html

Comment: В Windows она по умолчанию memmove, а в линуксе я переопределяю, после того как долго и упорно искал ошибку возникающую только на линуксе.

Comment: Ваш код имеет undefined behavior(неопределённое поведение), о чём Вам и указал @Igor. Поменяйте `memcpy` на `memmove`

Answer (score 1):

читайте коротенький код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char str[80] = "faE1*fe A3iBVf Oq eof 43GFW2jiqe[ qe";
    char token[80];

    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(str); i++)
        token[i - 1] = str[i];

    cout << token << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: я хочу понять принцип работы while

Comment: если коротко рассказывать то все что заключено в блок while то оно будет повторятся пока его условие истинно (то что в скобках)

Comment: Спасибо, буду дальше разбираться

Answer (score 0):

```
void F10(char* string)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        string[i - 1] = string[i];
    }
    string[strlen(string)-1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: медленно из-за постоянно вызываемой `strlen` и ненадёжной, из-за неправильно обрабатываемого случая, когда при входе пустая строка.

Comment: По сути это дубликат почти восьмилетнего [ответа от @perfect](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429849/386633)